# How to extract metadata of a word from Wikipedia?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, wikipedia

I am trying to automate hyper parameter tuning of my model classifier. Currently, the classifier spits out a probability for a given word, if its a food item or not. For example,

```
au_jus,0.987698
xiao_long_bao,0.9999957701
masago,0.9999957472
andouille_sausage,0.9999957196
-chicken,0.9999956648
broccoli_carrots,0.9999956072
sora,0.9999955529
```

I need to figure out false positives from the list of words. Instead of manually going through each of the words and checking. I was wondering, if I can query Wikipedia about the word and check the meta-data. If its listed under 'Food' category. Then probably my classifier is doing a good job. Else, its a false positive. The main idea is to automate the process.

I initially thought of wikipedia as a source for this. Any other alternatives / methods are welcomed. I don't mind posting the code, but it seems irrelevant to my current problem. Thus, I am not posting it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to query [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/) instead of Wikipedia. As its website says, DBPedia "is a crowd-sourced community effort to extract structured information from Wikipedia and make this information available on the Web". You can easily query the database with SPARQL, for example, to collect all items that are of type "Food". The automatic query builder shows [some of the output of that query](http://querybuilder.dbpedia.org/index.php?patterns=%5B%7B%22s%22%3A%22%3Ffood%22%2C%22p%22%3A%22rdf%3Atype%22%2C%22o%22%3A%22db-ont%3AFood%22%2C%22otype%22%3A%22uri%22%7D%5D#).